# txt file will not open, c++

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

This program is supposed to read a .txt file into an array, I do not know if it has something to do with the file path or the code in general. The X's are just a placeholder for my username. I know I can put the files in the project file, but I need to pull it from the computer. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream StuAns;
char stuAns[20];

StuAns.open("C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\Desktop\\StudentAnswers.txt");
if (!StuAns)
    cout << "ERORR: File did not open\n";

while (int count = 0 < 20 && StuAns >> stuAns[20])
        count++;

StuAns.close();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    cout << stuAns[i];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What, explicitly, isn't working?  Are you getting an error?  What is the error?

Comment: when I test to see if the file is open it comes back false, then a weird bar with two lines in the middle is printed 20 times.

Answer (score 2):

If `StuAns.open()` fails, you are not stopping your program, you are continuing on and trying to read from an unopened file and output unread data.

Also, `open()` doesn't tell you WHY it failed.  If you need that info, you will have to use the Win32 API `CreateFile()` function directly, then you can query `GetLastError()` if `CreateFile()` fails.

That being said, there are several bugs in your code:

- `StuAns[]` contains uninitialized data, which is what you end up seeing output in the final `for` loop.
- reading `StuAns >> stuAns[20]` goes out of bounds of the array. Valid indexes are `0..19` only. You are trashing memory (if the file were opened successfully).
- your `while` loop is coded wrong.
- you need to use `count` instead of `20` in the final `for` loop.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream StuAns;
    char stuAns[20] = {};
    int count = 0;

    StuAns.open("C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\Desktop\\StudentAnswers.txt");
    if (!StuAns.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: File did not open\n";
        return -1;
    }

    while (count < 20 && StuAns >> stuAns[count])
        count++;

    StuAns.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        cout << stuAns[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```